# Cómo llenar con datos una migracion en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

quisiera saber como puedo crear una migración en laravel con datos. Ya que tengo catálogos con datos precisos.
Por ejemplo:
1-Departamento RH
2-Departamento Financiero
En mi migración creo la tabla cat_departamenos con un id_depto y la descripción del departamento.

Gracias

Comment: Si, es como lo estaba manejando actualmente pero quería saber si existia otra opción aparte de los seeders.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema de los seeders? En ellos puedes establecer también datos concretos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si por alguna razón no quieres usar Seeders, se me ocurre que puedes hacer algo así:

```
Schema::create('cat_departamenos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('id_depto');
    $table->string('descripcion');
});


$data = [
    ['id_depto' => 1, 'descripcion'=> 'Departamento RH'],
    ['id_depto' => 2, 'descripcion'=> 'Departamento Financiero'],
    //...
];

Model::insert($data);
```

Y al correr la migración se creará la tabla y se insertarán los datos.

Comment: Esta es la opción que estaba buscando, muchas gracias! Lo probaré

Comment: @IsraelGutierrez ten en cuenta que usé Model como un nombre genérico, debes reemplazarlo por el nombre del modelo que corresponde a la tabla 'cat_departamenos'. También hice un edit para que quede correcto el valor del campo 'id_depto'